# Does modern compilers use copy elision when using the builder pattern

Tags: c++, c++17, builder

I am using a few builder patterns in my code base and I was wondering whether return by value should be favoured over the return by reference, given that is the push I am feeling with modern C++.  The example, in my opinion, would generate loads of copies if I applied the return by value approach.

```
class EmailBuilder
{
  public:
    EmailBuilder from(const string &from) {
        m_email.m_from = from;
        return *this;
    }
    
    EmailBuilder  to(const string &to) {
        m_email.m_to = to;
        return *this;
    }
    
    EmailBuilder  subject(const string &subject) {
        m_email.m_subject = subject;
        return *this;
    }
    
    EmailBuilder  body(const string &body) {
        m_email.m_body = body;
        return *this;
    }
    
    operator Email&&() {
        return std::move(m_email);  
    }
    
  private:
    Email m_email;
};

EmailBuilder Email::make()
{
    return EmailBuilder();
}

int main()
{
    Email mail = Email::make().from("me@mail.com")
                              .to("you@mail.com")
                              .subject("C++ builders")
                              .body("message");
                              

}
```

My question is whether is if compilers would optimise the many copies generated here. As I see it, for each of the function class we generate a new copy of the builder.

Comment: What do you feel is the benefit of returning by value here?

Comment: I actually dont know. But I have always been told to favour value semantics when it is affordable

Comment: If you return by value here, you will create 5 (if I count correctly) instances of `EmailBuilder` instead of just one. Compare with [this](https://godbolt.org/z/49YdraGef)

Comment: Why don't you just check? Start with a single field which prints on construction and on assignment (copy and move), and see how many times it's actually constructed. Also, it's not just the copy elision that you need, you need recognition of a pattern larger than that; and with heap-allocated memory, I doubt compilers will oblige you.

Comment: @ATK I would suggest that you learn the reasoning behind that advice, rather than following it blindly. It doesn’t apply to the code you’ve written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many cases where returning by value is favored since it typically side-steps life-time issue. This is not one of those cases because life-time of the builder is usually well defined and well understood. Thus returning by reference should be favored.

Also, in C++20 you can use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers):

```
#include <string>

struct Email {
    std::string from    = "unknown";
    std::string to      = "unknown";
    std::string subject = "unknown";
    std::string body    = "unknown";
};

int main() {
    Email email = {
        .from   = "me@example.com",
        .to     = "you@example.com",
        .body   = "This is my email"
    };
}
```

([See online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r9KvhMv5j))

Here, subject is left "unknown".